# Async function finishes too early

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Let's look at the following code:

```
class C
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task t = new Task(DoSthAsync);
        t.Start();
        t.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Finished?");
    }

    static async void DoSthAsync()
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
        {
            int i = 1;
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i++, await reader.ReadLineAsync());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get really confused. Shouldn't this code work synchronously since I am directly awaiting async method? From a 1000 line file I get only 76 lines printed. Why is that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using `async void` which [you should never do unless you are working with events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). First you need to make your function return a `Task` instead of void, you then must use `Task.Run` instead of `new Task` so that it can handle the async function for you.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task t = Task.Run(() => DoSthAsync()); // "Task.Run((Func<Task>)DoSthAsync)" would also work.
    t.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Finished?");
}

static async Task DoSthAsync()
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
    {
        int i = 1;
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i++, await reader.ReadLineAsync());
        }
    }
}
```

Your old way had no way of knowing that the inner task was complete, `t.Wait()` was only waiting till the first non synchronous completion of `reader.ReadLineAsync()`, by returning a `Task` your outer function now has a way to detect when the inner function is fully complete and not just waiting for its first continuation.

Comment: `DoSthAsync` still is not returning a `Task`; the compiler is going to be unhappy.

Comment: @MetroSmurf Why do you think it does not return a Task here?

Comment: @MetroSmurf no, it should be perfectly happy, you don't need a `return` statement in a `async Task` function, you only need one for a `async Task<T>` function and then you only return `T` not `Task<T>`.

Comment: It might be helpful to future readers to add a link to the source for the "don't use async void" part for those who don't know why it is a guideline.

Comment: @EdT Added a link to "Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming" from MSDN Magazine.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - my misunderstanding of `async`; I had no idea you could use async and return a Task w/o returning anything. When I look at this in VS, I'm getting an ambiguous reference with `Task.Run(DoSthAsync);` - should it be: `Task.Run((Func<Task>)DoSthAsync)`?

Comment: @MetroSmurf Yes, or use `Task.Run(() => DoSthAsync());`, either will work. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score -2):

You need to hold on the main thread as when new thread gets spawned for the task, it works but your main thread exists before even task gets complete.

You have to make sure that main thread does exit before your worker threads finishes up.

May you can use mutex